# show div after click and start timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, fadein

want to show a div after click on a button and then the time start and count from 10 to 0 .

my probelm is i don't know how to start count ?

javascript :

```
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
$('div#test').hide().delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

button :

```
 <div id="test" style="display:none;">click</div>
```

html :

```
<div id="test" style="display:none;">here you are !</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either setTimeout() or setInterval() to get it working:

Below is how I did it:

```
    $(function() {
$("button").click(function() {
    function counter()  {  
        var i = 10;
        $("body").append('<div style="border:1px solid red;">Div Created on the Fly</div>')
        function showDIV() {

        if (i < 0)
            return 
        setTimeout(showDIV, 1000);
        $("span").text(i);
        i--;        

    }

    showDIV();
}
counter(10);
});

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4XVMe/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` for counting.

```
var count = 10;
var temp = setInterval(function(){
  if(count < 0) {
      clearInterval(temp);
   }
  // show count 
  count--;


}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 15;
var timerID = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
    $('div#test').hide().delay(200).fadeIn('slow', function() {
         timerID = setInterval(function() {countDown();}, 1000);  // count every 1000 ms, change this to whatever you want
    });
    $("#wait").show();  // or you could fade this in if you want. Maybe that's what you intended with #test.
});

function countDown() {
    count--;
    $("#count").text(count);
    // do whatever you want to do with your count
    if (count <= 0) {
         clearInterval(timerID);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="wait" style="display:none">Please wait<span id="count">15</span> seconds...</p>
```

Assuming you wanted to start the count down after the fadeIn. Otherwise, just pull that piece out and setInterval after the fadeIn line which will start the countdown when the button is first clicked.

Comment: what i want to do something like "please wait 15 second" after click on the button

Comment: @Michaelroshdy: See my edits. You need an element for you count (and `span` makes sense because it's inline) and then when the `countDown()` function fires, you will change the `.text()` in that element.

Comment: did you test it !, it doesn't work as it should be, the time start after the div show ! what actually should happen after click 1- "please wait 15 sec" and then disappear and then show test div

Comment: @Michaelroshdy: If you don't spell out how it's supposed to work, then how is anybody supposed to help you? To do what you want just move the div fadeIn to the countDown function after the count < 0.